# Spark unit tests (in intellij)

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have some Spark unit tests in my intellij project. When I launch them one by one (file by file) everything is OK. When I want to test all the package, I have got :

> An exception or error caused a run to abort: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true.

I have read that setting spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts to true is dangerous :-/

Is there a way to tell intellij to run tests one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark itself comes with unit tests that use a trait with [a shared Spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/SharedSparkContext.scala) context, so you don't have to use multiple ones. You can copy that and use it in your own tests.

I however still ran into some issues where tests in IntelliJ were accessing the context in parallel. It is possible to have all your tests run in serial, but I use the following version of the trait with a lock such that *only* Spark tests are run in serie, other tests can still run in parallel:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.scalatest._

import scala.concurrent.Lock

object Spark {
  val lock = new Lock()
}

trait Spark extends BeforeAndAfterAll { self: Suite =>
  @transient private var _sc: SparkContext = _

  def sc: SparkContext = _sc

  var conf = new SparkConf(false)

  override def beforeAll() {
    Spark.lock.acquire()
    _sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "test", conf)
    super.beforeAll()
  }

  override def afterAll() {
    if (_sc != null) {
      _sc.stop()
    }
    Spark.lock.release()

    // To avoid Akka rebinding to the same port, since it doesn't unbind immediately on shutdown
    System.clearProperty("spark.driver.port")

    _sc = null
    super.afterAll()
  }
}
```

You can use this trait in your tests like so:

```scala
class MySpec extends FlatSpec with Spark {
  "I" should "be able to use Spark" in {
    sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
  }
}
```

Comment: Look a perfect solution but why do i have import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, Suite} that raise object scalatest is not a member of package org.  I have this in my build.sbt :   "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.2.1" % "test",

Comment: I wasn't sure, but I see you put it into a separate question. Let us know if it works with that.

Comment: It kind of works but i had to put this file in the src/test/scala directory instead of src/main/scala. So I have to puplicate it in all my projects :-/ Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In each test, at the end of the test, close the spark context and create it again at the beginning of the next test:

`sparkContext.stop()`

And:

```
val sparkContext = new SparkContext()
```